# HSQLDB sqllog error

Tags: java, hsqldb, cisco, netflow

I'm using Cisco Configuration Professional and I have some issues with the Netflow collector. After a series of attempts and guessing I restricted the problem to a database problem. In particular the collector is able to write in the database only netflow version 1 flows.
The database that CCP is using is hsqldb. 
As I wanted to find out why it's not writing the flows I tried to log every query issued using both `hsqldb.sqllog` (appended in the hsqldb url) and `SET DATABASE EVENT LOG SQL LEVEL 3` but they are unsuccessful (they start a java exception). Are there any parameters that are preventing sql logging ? It's a java.class file that have to be added to hsqldb.jar package to be used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the HSQLDB jar manifest or the .properties file of the database for the jar version. Only more recent versions support `.sqllog`. You should be able to replace the jar with the latest 2.3.4 version (currently Release Candidate).

Comment: you were right, CCP used an embedded version that was too old. I wrongly assumed that sql logging has always been a hsqldb feature. Now `.sqllog` it's working fine

Comment: Which version was used?

Comment: This one : `hsqldb-2.0.0`